# Practical use of sender & EventArgs in Page_Load

Tags: asp.net

I am on the verge migrating all my asp.net WebForms skills to asp.net mvc. So far, I never felt a need to use `EventArgs` and `sender` argument, passed to `Page_Load`.

Can you please point me a couple of scenario, when you leverage theses parameters?

Comment: `Page_Load` is defined as an event handler, meaning it has to have these parameters. They are not normally used. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx

Comment: I'm curious, why did you migrate ? I was thinking of doing it but still with asp.net webforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All event handlers follow the same pattern, i.e. they have a sender parameter and an arguments parameter.

The event handler for the `Load` event very rarely make use of either, because you almost (?) always have one event handler for each form or control (so you already know which object sent the event), and there is no specific data send in the arguments parameter.

You use the sender parameter when you use the same handler for more than one event, to find out where the event came from. You use the arguments parameter for some event where there is some specific data sent to the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You never will use EventArgs or Sender, never will use Page_Load method

Because MVC manage calls as Actions

EventArgs result of parse a POST

So if you need any thing in eventargs in your old code, in the new you should past this as formcollection